# IPSEC site-to-site overlaping networks

Tags: vpn, iptables, ufw, nat, ipsec

we have two sides connected over ipsec using strongswan. both machines ubuntu 16.04 servers. the issue is both end subnets are overlapping. we have tried all possible iptables scenarios to map addresses but no luck. forwarding, ufw, netmap, snat, dnat. we are using ufw on both sides. any ideas?

Comment: Please tell us specifically what commands you tried, and their result, else we may end up researching things you've already tried. Please click [edit] and put the command used and what the response was into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found fix from strongswan page:

https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/net2net-same-nets/