# how to configure nat on shorewall for overlapping networks?

Tags: firewall

we have two servers with overlapping networks, both servers using shorewall as default firewall, both servers connected via l2l vpn strongswan, as networks overlapping we have connectivity issue. how to nat this networks on shorewall? both server ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Netmap via IPtables. Suggest you read the docs:
https://shorewall.org/netmap.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm sure you can write a more extensive answer than this.

Comment: we tried this guide but didnt help

Comment: please post comment only who had deal with this situation!!!

Comment: Thought the OP had solved it a few months ago: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226792/ipsec-site-to-site-overlaping-networks  Said they were using strongswan and had overlapping networks.

Comment: there iptables not shorewall

Comment: Shorewall reads iptables rules and is a front-end, basically. But you had said you solved this months ago.  https://shorewall.org/Introduction.html#Shorewall

Comment: we moved to shorewall from iptables, now need to do same trick on shorewall

Comment: Right. The "What is Shorewall" page says:  "Shorewall reads those configuration files and with the help of the iptables, iptables-restore, ip and tc utilities, Shorewall configures Netfilter and the Linux networking subsystem to match your requirements. "  So if you already have iptables working...Shorewall can use those same rules.

Comment: have you configured shorewall? especially netmap or mangle?

Comment: Yep and thats why I'm suggesting you go through those docs again. Your missing the obvious.

Comment: ok, if you configured, how to figure out mangle on shorewall for strongswan? can you give me example?

Comment: Like I said, read the docs. Already has ipsec examples. https://shorewall.org/IPSEC-2.6.html

Comment: we read this doc many times and tried many times, its not wotking

Comment: You asked for examples and I gave you examples. And "not wotking" isn't much of a problem description.

Comment: i know how to use google :) before this post i read all materials. if you have real suggestion, if you really configured similar situation, please give right advice not google search :) if you cant please hold on, as i posted -> please post comment only who had deal with this situation!!!

Comment: Dude don't know what you want here. You asked and got told the answer that shorewall uses iptables and is a front-end. if you already got iptables working what's the issue? You wanted examples and you were given examples and now your complaining and making comments about google? If you're expecting people to give you exact, 100% type this in and its gonna work commands, not gonna happen. You have to do some things yourself.

Comment: shorewall.org/Introduction.html#Shorewall am going to mark this as solved if you agree that its right way

Comment: If you're asking if I think you should read the docs and follow the instructions as being the right way that'd be yes. Don't you get what shorewall is and how it works? uses iptables which you said you had working. don't even know why you have an issue then. Their docs have examples and you didnt look at them. Dunno what else you want.

Comment: you really didnt ever worked with strongswan and shorewall!!! please do not comment this issue!!!

Comment: Whatever. If you don't get what you're doing then there isn't anything to tell you. You asked for examples and got them. You claim to know how to get it done with iptables and know shorewall but don't seem to understand what shorewall is. Now you want to complain? Get somebody else at wherever you are to explain it to you. Done.